# Netbeans Git shows non-existent changes

Tags: git, netbeans

I do not know if the problem is Netbeans related or Git related.

Sometimes I see that some files are modified.

[image]

[image]

But when I open diff I do not see any changes and moreover I know that changes were not performed.

[image]

So why it happens?
May it be because the files are used in Linux server and on my local Windows? So maybe it is because some linebreaks troubles? But I am sure that files were not opeed and saves even without code changes.

This issue confuses me because it is hard to track files that were really modified by me. It appears sometimes (but not each time) after I pull changes from remote server.

How can I avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that NetBeans ignores whitespaces for the diff. See 
Options/Misc/Diff to configure this behaviour.

Also invoke `git status` on the command line to see the real status.

Comment: The files are 100% identical, because there were many cases when I definitely know that the files were not modified. So whitespaces setting were not affect. git status does not show changes